# Delete multiple table cells from specific row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to delete multiple table cells from a row, and I have an array which store the indexes of table cells to be deleted. But it deleted only alternative cells. I don't have much knowledge in query.

Here is My code is.

```
var current_row_id=$(this).parent()[0].id;
var row_elem=document.getElementById(current_row_id);

for(var count=0;count<before_lunchstart_array.length;count++) {
    $('#'+current_row_id+' td').each (function(index) {
        if(index==before_lunchstart_array[count]) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Just from the looks of it, your index may not actually correspond to the id in your array. Keep in mind jquery.each indexes at 0, meaning the first value of index will be 0.

Comment: `before_lunchstart_array[count]` what do you have in it?

Comment: before_lunchstart_array contains the indexes to be deleted

Comment: @user2637613 do you have any id or className to your table.

Comment: @Binni i have posted an answer..did u saw dat??

Comment: ya... but I don't want to delete cells from every row so I have also used a table row id stored in a variable "current_row_id". Then I have changed the code like this for(var count=0;count<before_lunchstart_array.length;count++) {
    $('.datatable #'+current_row_id+' td:eq('+ before_lunchstart_array[count] +')').remove();
   }. But it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this without any `.each()` loop but for this you have to use this way:

```
$('yortblID/Class td:eq('+ before_lunchstart_array[count] +')').remove();
```

---

I think you are checking for index with count index in `before_lunchstart_array` array so instead you can do this with `.eq()` its index start from 0, still it will remove all those tds which `index === before_lunchstart_array[count]`.

So  `.eq(before_lunchstart_array[count])` is equal to `index === before_lunchstart_array[count]`.

Comment: I tried this too. but before_lunchstart_array contains 49,50,51,52 and it deleted cells of indexes 49,51,53,55

Comment: @Binni would you post your table rows too in your post.

Comment: table rows are dynamically created, number of table rows depends on database content.